# ReSharper 2016.1.2 intellisense messed up in .NET Core 1.0 Razor Views

Tags: c#, razor, resharper, asp.net-core-1.0

ReSharper 2016.2 is not playing well with the latest project template for ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web Application.

It is not understanding Model, Layout, ViewData or any other Razor syntax in my views. Everything is underlined Red and it is making randomusing statement recommendations.

Is anyone else having this issue that is working with the latest versions of Core 1.0 and R#? I already tried clearing the ReSharper cache and no go.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. With VS 2015 Update 3 and Resharper Ultimate 2016.1.2.

Updating to Resharper 2016.2 fixed my issue.

if it doesn't work for you then add .cshtml in ignore list of resharper.

Go to **Resharper > Options > Settings** 
And add ***.cshtml** in the **File masks**

[image: Screenshot]